# How to disable depth clearing in Unity URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

Im trying to write a snow shader with displacement and secondary camera to render depth to RenderTexture. But it clears every frame and snow tracks are not rendering because of that.[unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@10.5/manual/cameras-advanced.html) says that there is no simple way around it. Im using URP version 12.1.8

As far as i understand, to modify clear logic i need to write my own SRP, but i really would not want that, especially because in built-in render pipeline this problem was solved with a single checkbox.
I've tried creating a compute shader to add data from camera's rt to a separate rt, but it feels wrong so i would like to know: is there a simpler way?
Also here is the exact line from UniversalRenderPipeline.cs which restricts Base camera from not clearing the texture by changing clearDepth value, so i wonder can i copy all code from the original URP and change just that line?

```
if (isSceneViewCamera)
        {
            cameraData.renderType = CameraRenderType.Base;
            cameraData.clearDepth = true;
            cameraData.postProcessEnabled = CoreUtils.ArePostProcessesEnabled(camera);
            cameraData.requiresDepthTexture = settings.supportsCameraDepthTexture;
            cameraData.requiresOpaqueTexture = settings.supportsCameraOpaqueTexture;
            cameraData.renderer = asset.scriptableRenderer;
        }
        else if (additionalCameraData != null)
        {
            cameraData.renderType = additionalCameraData.renderType;
            cameraData.clearDepth = (additionalCameraData.renderType != CameraRenderType.Base) ? additionalCameraData.clearDepth : true;
            cameraData.postProcessEnabled = additionalCameraData.renderPostProcessing;
            cameraData.maxShadowDistance = (additionalCameraData.renderShadows) ? cameraData.maxShadowDistance : 0.0f;
            cameraData.requiresDepthTexture = additionalCameraData.requiresDepthTexture;
            cameraData.requiresOpaqueTexture = additionalCameraData.requiresColorTexture;
            cameraData.renderer = additionalCameraData.scriptableRenderer;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using compute shader to add depth from current frame to RT
input texture is camera target texture(make sure that its depth only)
result must be rgb texture

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> _Result;
Texture2D<float4> _InputTexture;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{  
    float4 resultColor = _Result[id.xy];
    float4 inp = _InputTexture[id.xy];
    _Result[id.xy] = max(resultColor,inp);
}
```